# Ultrafilters preserving infinite joins

Tags: boolean-algebras, ultrafilters

A filter $U$ over a boolean algebra (isomorphic to a powerset) $A$ "preserves" a join $a = \bigcup_{i\in I}a_i$, if $a\in U$ implies $a_i\in U$ for some $i\in I$. (A join $a$ is infinite if $I$ is.) There exist ultrafilters preserving countable sets of infinite joins and, moreover, for an arbitrary non-zero element $e \in A$, there is such an ultrafilter containing $e$.

The question is: if we have given a subset $S\subset A$ with finite intersection property (each non-empty finite subset $T\subseteq S$ has a non-zero meet), and a countable collection of infinite joins in $A$, does there exist an ultrafilter containing $S$ and preserving these joins? If the general answer is negative, are there any additional conditions on $A$ or $S$ which ensure the existence of such an ultrafilter?

Answer (score 4):

In general, this is false: if you take any join $a=\bigvee_{i\in I}a_i$ which is essentially infinite (i.e., $a$ is not the join of any finite subset of the $a_i$s), then the set $S=\{a\}\cup\{-a_i:i\in I\}$ has fip, and no ultrafilter containing $S$ preserves the join $a=\bigvee_{i\in I}a_i$.

For a positive result, such an ultrafilter exists under the following additional assumption: for each join $a=\bigvee_{i\in I}a_i$ that we want to preserve, and for every $b\in A$ such that $S\cup\{a,b\}$ has fip, there exists $i\in I$ such that $S\cup\{a_i,b\}$ has fip. [Proof: construct a sequence $b_0\ge b_1\ge\dots$ such that $S\cup\{b_n\}$ has fip, and $b_n$ “decides” the $n$th join in the sense that either $b_n\le a_i$ for some $i\in I$, or $b_n\le-a$. Then extend $S\cup\{b_n:n<\omega\}$ to an ultrafilter.]

You may consider this to be a Boolean version of the omitting types theorem.